# SQL Server 2005 Split email text field to a view table

Tags: parsing, sql-server-2005, view

Having read through multiple, very good, high powered options for splitting delimited text columns I have come to the conclusion that I need assistance dumbing it down for a relative newbie to SQL Server.

Explanation of the issue: I am at the mercy of the previous programmer. Sigh. We have an (1) email column entry for shipments in our existing *unmodifiable* system. When we have more than one receiver we place multiple emails in the column delimited by commas (BAD design !!!).

A shipper has edited their program to accept multiple key columns and manually split the email column into separate email columns. Other shipper's programs can't be changed. I am using MY view table for concatenated key columns to feed the data to the secondary programs - which works for all instances except when the email column contains more than one email address.

Explanation of (a) Resolution:

I need the original email column intact in the view table and (5) more columns added to my view table with a *possible* email address parsed from the original column. This needs to work for the existing rows and any future rows. I assume that one AlterTable or AlterView statement will do the trick.

TIA++

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would be great

Comment: write a `Function` to split values and return `Table` and then use that function with `SELECT` and `JOIN`

Comment: Sounds like a decent string splitter and some triggers may be in your future. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: John - I will attempt to create a sample table and view to post.

Comment: techspider - does creating a new table update my view automatically on new data entry to the original table?

Comment: Sean - Thanks for the link. This is another long article with examples of multiple methods of achieving a split. Not helpful to my circumstance as OP. I will research 'triggers' to see if I can understand their usage. I was under the impression that my 'view' table automatically updates every time new data is entered in the original table.